# Deleting an element from XML document and saving over old file

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

*EDIT: ok, so I got the program to delete, the line `foreach (var elem in doc.Document.Descendants("Profiles"))` needed "Profile" instead. BUT now in my XML doc there is an empty Profile Element for each one deleted, so If all the items in the xml example(at bottom of question) get deleted I'm left with this:***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Profiles>
  <Profile />
  <Profile />
</Profiles>
```

=========================ORIGINAL QUESTION BELOW=================================

I'm using the following code to remove a element and it's children from an XML file, BUT it isn't removing them from the file upon saving. Could someone let me know why this is incorrect?

```
    public void DeleteProfile()
    {
        var doc = XDocument.Load(ProfileFile);
        foreach (var elem in doc.Document.Descendants("Profiles"))
        {
            foreach (var attr in elem.Attributes("Name"))
            {
                if (attr.Value.Equals(this.Name))
                    elem.RemoveAll();
            }
        }
        doc.Save(ProfileFile,
        MessageBox.Show("Deleted Successfully");
    }
```

EDIT: an example of the XML format below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Profiles>
  <Profile Name="MyTool">
    <ToolName>PC00121</ToolName>
    <SaveLocation>C:\Users\13\Desktop\TestFolder1</SaveLocation>
    <Collections>True.True.True</Collections>
  </Profile>
  <Profile Name="TestProfile">
    <ToolName>PC10222</ToolName>
    <SaveLocation>C:\Users\14\Desktop\TestFolder2</SaveLocation>
    <Collections>True.False.False</Collections>
  </Profile>
</Profiles>
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging this and making sure there were elements removed in the first place?  Perhaps there was nothing removed and you just re-saved the same exact file again?

Comment: that's sorta what I think was/is happening, I'm just not familiar enough with XML to know if I'm even doing a delete appropriately. I'll go debug again and see what I can deduct, but I'll also toss an example from the xml in the question as well in case its clear to the community whats wrong here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you want to remove a profile given its name:

```
private static void RemoveProfile(string profileFile, string profileName)
{
    XDocument xDocument = XDocument.Load(profileFile);
    foreach (var profileElement in xDocument.Descendants("Profile")  // Iterates through the collection of "Profile" elements
                                            .ToList())               // Copies the list (it's needed because we modify it in the foreach (when the element is removed)
    {
        if (profileElement.Attribute("Name").Value == profileName)   // Checks the name of the profile
        {
            profileElement.Remove();                                 // Removes the element
        }
    }
    xDocument.Save(profileFile);
}
```

If you have only an empty element is because you use `RemoveAll()` (removes the descendants and attributes of an element) instead of `Remove()` (removes the element it self from its parent).

You can even remove the `if` by replacing it by a `where` in the LINQ query:

```
foreach (var profileElement in (from profileElement in xDocument.Descendants("Profile")      // Iterates through the collection of "Profile" elements
                                where profileElement.Attribute("Name").Value == profileName  // Checks the name of the profile
                                select profileElement).ToList())                             // Copies the list (it's needed because we modify it in the foreach (when the element is removed)
    profileElement.Remove();  // Removes the element

xDocument.Save(profileFile);
```

Comment: I solved this, but your answer is slightly cleaner and more elegant, so I'll go ahead and choose this one

Answer (score 0):

```
....
foreach (var elem in doc.Document.Descendants("Profiles"))
{
    foreach (var attr in elem.Attributes("Name"))
    {
           if (attr.Value.Equals(this.Name))
               TempElem = elem;
    }
}
TempElem.Remove();
...
```

I'm dumb lol, this solves everything