# How to delete an XML element from a txt file in C#

Tags: c#, xml, dictionary, xml-serialization

To use a XML serialized `Dictionary,` I use the [SerializableDictionary](http://weblogs.asp.net/pwelter34/archive/2006/05/03/444961.aspx) class. For write and read a `SerializableDictionary` in a TXT file, I use these methods:

```
// Write
public static void WriteOnFile(string pathFile)
{
   XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SerializableDictionary<string, double>));
   using (FileStream fs = File.OpenWrite(pathFile))
   {
      using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fs))
      {
         serializer.Serialize(fs, databaseMateriali);
      }
   }
}

// Read
public static SerializableDictionary<string, double> ReadFromFile(string pathFile)
{
   SerializableDictionary<string, double> elencoLetto = new SerializableDictionary<string, double>();
   using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(pathFile))
   {
      using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fs))
      {
         fs.Position = 0;
         XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SerializableDictionary<string, double>));
         SerializableDictionary<string, double> clone = (SerializableDictionary<string, double>)serializer.Deserialize(fs);
                    elencoLetto = clone;
      }
   }
   return elencoLetto;
}
```

How can I delete an XML element from this TXT file, without erasing and rewriting the entire file?

Comment: Just erase and rewrite (or overwrite) the entire file. It's okay. There is no general solution to this problem; let the file-system handle the IO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to remove bytes from a file. You can mark your data so you can have a program logic to not use it. That way the file stays the same number of bytes but your logic can "delete" parts of it. But your class does not seem to support this, so you will have to just rewrite the entire file after removing the entry in memory.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Ok, and if instead of saving in a TXT file, I save in a XML document? (In this case, I would open a new thread so as not to go OT).

Comment: It does not depend on the file format. You cannot remove bytes from a file once written. No matter what format. You can only overwrite it with the new contents completely.

Comment: Ok. Forgive me one last question: thus, what is shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8382834/how-to-remove-an-xml-element-from-file) or [here,](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17840688/deleting-an-element-from-xml-document-and-saving-over-old-file) does nothing more than to completely rewrite the file with the updated data?

Comment: Both answer load it all, manipulate it in memory and write it all back to disk, overwriting the previous file.